# Need to scrape price from an ecommerce website using xpath

Tags: php, mysql, xpath

I need to extract the price of a specific product from an e-commerce website using Dom and XPath and save it to a MySQL database.

I have tried

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-star-pro-s7262/p/itmdqq6zfh7y7enm?pid=MOBDQ22YUJ8ZFXKW&srno=b_1&ref=0545bfb1-043b-479f-aca2-a468e03f0c34');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
*$nodelist = $xpath->query("id('topsection')/x:div[3]/x:div[2]/x:div[1]/x:div/x:div[1]/x:div/x:span");*
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

This code works for things like getting the urls, page title etc.

But when I tried using it to get price from that particular url using xpath, it got nothing.What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Welcome on SO! This site is meant for help with programming questions, but some efforts by the asker himself is expected. If you post some code what you have tried and come up with a specific pitfall/problem we can help, but unfortunately we cannot guide you through anything step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks giorgio! I am looking for a sample working script as I have no programming experience.This is something I wanna implement on my website.I found a few scripts online but none of them seem to work.I am sure if someone posts a working example, I can learn a lot from it and know why my previous attempts failed

Comment: Sorry, but can't help :) We don't do script requests here, not even sample scripts. However, our great friend [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=scrape+site+dom+with+xpath) is of great help here. Top result is even another question on SO. So please, first do some searching yourself, enough to find! Then after some trial and error come back with specific problems or buggy code you can't fix.

Comment: Please don't post code as comments, but edit your original question. Code in comments is barely unreadable. Make also sure to describe what the actual output is, what output you expect and as detailed as possible the problem you have. Once you edited your question, it will very probably get reopened and answered soon.

Answer (score 0):

since the site uses some microdata, you could use those in your query.
That way you'll be less dependent on the markup structure:

```
$query = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@itemprop, 'price')]");

//loop over the results accessing the content attribute
foreach ($query as $result) {
    var_dump($result->getAttribute('content'));
}

//or
echo sprintf(
  "%s %s",
  $query->item(0)->getAttribute('content'),
  $query->item(1)->getAttribute('content')
);
```

see http://dev.w3.org/html5/md-LC/ & http://schema.org/docs/gs.html for more information: